# Is the remote controller adapter RA-E3 conversion cable sold outside the 60Da bundle?

Tags: canon, remote, adapter, triggers

Is the remote controller adapter RA-E3 conversion cable (or a third party equivalent) sold outside the 60Da bundle? Additionally will this cable work with any body having an E3 socket?

Comment: It would help if you would include what accessory you are attempting to use with what Canon body. There are many third party solutions that get around the need for this specific adapter.

Comment: While I couldn't find one, it would be relatively simple to make one yourself by cutting an N3 connector off one end of an N3 cable and connecting a commercially available headphone end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapter should work to allow any accessories with an N3 connector to be used with a Canon camera having an E3 (stereo mini plug) socket.

Amazon once sold [such an adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0079WIITW) in the U.S., but it is not currently available. However, many of the third party accessories that are available with one connector are also available with the other and are usually fairly cheap. There's even a [TC80N3 knockoff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A664V9O) that comes with adapters for almost every imaginable camera that uses the basic three wire shutter release.

This seller in the Netherlands currently lists [such an adapter](http://nl.aliexpress.com/item/Shutter-Remote-Terminal-Convert-Adapter-Cable-N3F-E3M/365832013.html) as available.
[This seller](http://monopoly.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2012/05/rae3-fb55.html) is presumably in Asia.

[image]

Comment: Great, but is it (or an equivalent) sold outside of the 60Da bundle?

Comment: What continent are you on?

Comment: Sometimes Europe, sometimes Asia

Comment: Once again a solid answer even taking my slightly unusual habit of living both in Europa and Asia into account! Simply perfect!